# do not compress just zip files in command line

Tags: tar, zip

I have a bunch of photos, around 2 GB size to be precise. I need to download these images but I have to zip it first.

Using zip command to compress the image files takes so much time to complete. I want to only zip those images in command line without compression. Is this possible?

Comment: If you don't want to compress them, then why do you need to zip them?

Comment: @psusi I want to download the images but compressing these images would take a lot of time to complete. So I just need a zipped file for all the images without compressing it (as compression makes the zip operation slow).

Comment: What is wrong with just downloading the files as is?  No need to waste disk space on a big archive then.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is what tarball archives are for.

```
tar -c -f archive.tar file directory/
```

This creates an uncompressed archive.

Answer (score 16):

With regular zip:

```
zip -0 -r mydirectory.zip mydirectory
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command (taken from the 7zip docs):

```
7z a archive.zip *.jpg -mx0
```

It should be available via the `p7zip-full` package.